# Choose header layout (header file) Advanced Custom Fields Theme Options Page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So, I've decided to make the leap to using ACF Pro to build a master template for our client sites. Thus far, we've been using a combination of Genesis/Dynamik Web Builder/Beaver Builder and, it has been pretty good for us but, not quite as quick and simple as we need it to be in building certain sites.

What I want to do is build a custom theme based on the [Underscores](https://underscores.me/) WordPress theme and build a theme options page using ACF Pro.

While I understand how to use ACF in more typical scenarios, I'd like to make it so the person building the site can select which header layout they want to use when building the site (ex: single row/full width, stacked layout, logo centered, logo left/right, etc. I'm thinking I'd like to do this by creating a field where if the user wants 'header style 1' the theme will use header-1.php, if they want to use header style 2 (stacked layout) it will call header-2.php for example.

How best to implement this for headers AND footers? Call different headers based on what the user selects or, call different content (divs, classes, markup in general) and output that to a common header file?

Here's an example I found that sort of does what I want but, it is on a per post basis and I need to do this globally and make it a selectable option in the ACF Pro Options page - https://wploop.com/change-header-footer-sidebar-custom-fields

I have searched here, on the Advanced Custom Fields website, their forums, and I have Googled for two straight days and found nothing that points me in the right direction. Also, I have posted in the ACF Pro forums asking the same question as well as in the Team Treehouse community.

I thank you in advance for your help!
Ray

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but since you are also using beaver builder, have you ever tried checking beaver tunnels? maybe this is the solution you are looking for.

- site: https://beavertunnels.com/blog/
- demo: http://tunnels.beaverjunction.com/
- youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgMQGHcWSk4

Comment: Gracias, Rafael Baylon! This could work a treat in my situation. Cheers!